# A special format of table of contents

Tags: formatting

I would like to create a table of contents that has the same format with the one in the picture. However, I could not realize how to add the word "Chapter" after Abstract, and also, how to put a single space between chapter titles. Thank you for your responses.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[font={small,it}]{caption}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\allsectionsfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\chapterfont{\normalsize\bfseries\centering}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
        \pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{document}
        \clearpage
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \setcounter{page}{3}
        \doublespacing
    \chapter*{ \centering{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}} 
    \begin{center}
            \renewcommand\contentsname{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
            \tableofcontents
    \end{center}                    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ABSTRACT}
    \chapter*{ABSTRACT}  
    \chapter {INTRODUCTION}
        \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \chapter {FORMULATION}
    \section{Laplace Domain Integral Equations} 
    \section{Method of Moments}
    \section{Discretization in Space Using Spatial Basis Functions}     
    \section{Discretization in Time Using the Finite Difference Delay Modeling Approach}        
    \section{Discretization in Time Using the Bandlimited Interpolation and Extrapolation Approach} 
    \subsection{Temporal Basis Functions}
    \subsection{Extrapolation and Marching on in Time}  
    \chapter {NUMERICAL RESULTS}    
    \chapter {CONCLUSION}
        \begin{thebibliography}{9}
            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{REFERENCES}
        \end{thebibliography}                       
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Does `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\textbf{\chaptername}\par}` just before your first `\chapter` command work?

Comment: Why did you change the question? Isn't the `Chapter` title not important any longer?

Comment: Start with `\documentclass` and build things up from there.

Comment: You might need to increase the tocdepth counter. chapter=0, section=1, subsection=2, subsubsection=3, paragraph=4, subparagraph=5.